# Xamarin Forms Animations work on iOS but not on Android

Tags: c#, android, animation, xamarin.forms, platform

I am trying to use simple animations in a basic new project. 
e.g.

```
await someImage.RotateTo(180, 5000, Easing.BounceIn);
```

But for some reason it does NOT seem to work on Android and it DOES work on iOS.

It seems to work on Xamarin.Forms version 2.5 but i am using the latest version (atm 4.2.0.709249).

Anyone who had the same problem and know a fix?

Thanks in advance

Jorg

Comment: Are you performing this action on MainThread?

Comment: Yes i have tried using "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread" but still no result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is broken on Android in the last version.
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7417

Downgrade to 4.1 or wait for a new version including the fix.

Comment: Tnx alot! that seems to fix it for now!